# Can't install modules from UI when site placed in subdirectory

Tags: 8, installation, .htaccess

I have Drupal 8 installed in a subfolder (`www.example.com/drupal`), and I have my root `.htaccess` configured to mask the subfolder (i.e. the URLs resolve to `www.example.com`; `/drupal` does not appear in the URLs).

Everything works great except when I try to install new modules I get a 403 error.  I see in the URL for `authorize.php` that `/drupal` now appears in the URL.  Where I would expect `www.example.com/core/authorize.php/`, I instead see `www.example.com/drupal/core/authorize.php/`.  I imagine this is the reason for the 403?

What additional modifications do I have to make to `/drupal/.htaccess` in order to get access to the `/core` files required to install new modules?

Here's what's in my document root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !drupal/
RewriteRule (.*) /drupal/$1 [L]
```

And the only modification to `/drupal/.htaccess` is to uncomment the subdirectory per the instructions in the file:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
RewriteBase /drupal
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment this line.

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
```

Another option is to update module using drush.

```
drush up
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did uncomment the line you mentioned (see above; that's the only thing I modded in /drupal/.htaccess).  I did end up figuring out that I could install modules via drush, too.  I almost prefer that to the website backend installer.  Still wish I knew what was going on with the .htaccess files, though.

Comment: Have you  checked what the error logs pointing out? Also did you configured a virtual host?

Comment: Yes, the web server is the right place to configure subdirectories, not Drupal.